# relatively prime sequences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For each natural number $n$, I'd like to build a sequence of $n$ relatively prime numbers such that, if $max(n)$ is the largest number in this sequence, then $max(n)$ doesn't grow too fast. What can I hope for here? For example, can I define a sequence of $n$ relatively prime numbers with $\max(n)$ bounded above by something better than a polynomial in $n$?

Comment: The prime numbers themselves form a relatively prime sequence, and $\max n$ in this case is asymptotic to $n\log n$. You are lucky.

Comment: There is no such sequence right now except the sequence of primes of course. To be honest, I have spent a great amount of time searching for such a sequence with no success. There is no such sequence known with logarithmic density. If you find one, let me know!